# How to fix compatibility warning of Akka with ReactiveMongo 0.20.3

Tags: scala, akka, reactivemongo

I have upgraded to reactive mongo 0.17.1 to 0.20.3. and after that I facing these warnings.

> [WARN] [03/17/2020 12:20:43.782] [main]
>   [ManifestInfo(akka://reactivemongo)] Detected possible incompatible
>   versions on the classpath. Please note that a given Akka version MUST
>   be the same across all modules of Akka that you are using, e.g. if you
>   use [2.5.25] all other modules that are released together MUST be of
>   the same version. Make sure you're using a compatible set of
>   libraries. Possibly conflicting versions [2.5.25, 2.5.11] in libraries
>   [akka-protobuf:2.5.25, akka-actor:2.5.25, akka-slf4j:2.5.11,
>   akka-stream:2.5.25]

Comment: Please format properly your question

Comment: That's a no fatal warn. ReactiveMongo works with Akka versions from 2.3 up to 2.6.

Comment: If you want to remove that warn, check your dependencyTree and exclude appropriately the akka dependency not wanted.

Comment: i think i resolved the issue, I override the older depedency by akka-actor:2.5.25. it stopped giving the error

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that it is not safe to mix different patch versions of Akka modules, they all need to be of the same version (you can read more about this in the [docs here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/common/binary-compatibility-rules.html#mixed-versioning-is-not-allowed).

Most often you can just add explicit dependencies in your build for the transitive ones to force them to be of the Akka version you want (2.5.25 in this case).